# How to remove features in an Image Layer, Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

So I'm checking to see if there is a way to delete features that exist on an Image layer in Openlayers 3 (e.g. `ol.layer.Image({})` ). Here's the code I use to create the layer:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Image({
    tethys_legend_title: titleName,
    zIndex: 1,
    source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: styleFunction,
    }),
});

// Make sure that the layer is not already existing, remove it if the layer does exist
map = TETHYS_MAP_VIEW.getMap();
for (i = 0; i < map.getLayers().getProperties().length ; i ++){
    if (map.getLayers().item(i).getProperties().tethys_legend_title === titleName)
        map.removeLayer(map.getLayers().item(i));
}
vector.tethys_legend_title = 'Water Table';
map.addLayer(vector);
```

The way I currently understand features that can be deleted in openlayers is through the `.removeFeature()` method. However, the `removeFeature()` method only applies to vector layers. Is there a way to delete features that pertain to Image layers? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the features from the original vectorSource?  You could get your features like this: `vector.getSource().getSource()`, then call `removeFeature` from there.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thank you! If you make it an answer I'll select it as the correct one.

I'm noticing that there is not a generic way to remove image layer features, so if the source for the image layer is not a vector feature then openlayers does not appear to have a general method for removing features from an image layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to access the vector source, which is within the Image source: `vector.getSource().getSource()`.  Then, you'll be able to use the `removeFeature` method from there, i.e. from the `ol.source.Vector` object returned..